# Finding index of first visible child in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function that finds the index of the first visible child. It works but I'm wondering if there's a faster/better way to do it:

```
var TheDiv = $('#' + TheDivID);
var CurrentIndex = 0;

TheDiv.children().each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        CurrentIndex = $(this).index();
        break;
    }
});
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `TheDiv` does already exists, add the selector in the `.children()` method, and use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the index of the element:

```
TheDiv.children(':visible').index();
```

Otherwise, use:

```
CurrentIndex = $('#' + TheDivID + ' > :visible').index();
```

Comment: I'm with you right up until you put `:visible:first` into the main DOM selection.

Comment: @amnotiam Oops, I agree, `:first` can be omitted, because it returns the index of the first element in the collection.

Comment: True, but I had `qSA` optimization more on the mind, which `:visible` will break as well. But that's me. When it comes to selector extensions, I'm pretty intolerant. ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Rob W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9353705/417562) is good, and probably the shortest way to write this code. However, it isn't necessarily the most efficient.

jQuery's custom selectors are *slow*. They're not a patch on native selectors that can use `querySelectorAll`. What's more, `children(':visible')` (or suchlike) *will* test every single element for visibility, even if that's not necessary for your application.  For instance, if you have 300 children and the first is visible, you don't need to test the next 299, but this method will do so.

So actually the approach you suggested in your question may not be too far away from the ideal. It wouldn't work as it is (`break` doesn't work in a jQuery selection) and `is` is phenomenally slow, but I think it can be cleaned up...

```
TheDiv.children().each(function (i) {
    if (jQuery.expr[':'].visible(this)) {
        CurrentIndex = i;
        return false;
    }
});
```

This uses `return false` to break out of the `each` loop. It also uses jQuery's filters (in a completely unorthodox and undocumented way) to test for visibility. The confusing line is exactly equivalent to `$(this).is(':visible')` except far, far quicker.

Since this breaks out of the loop as soon as a visible element is found, it may well be quicker than the selector-string method.

Comment: +1 for the optimized version, though at that point, we might as well just consider what is making it not visible, and test for that directly *(assuming the children are all invisible for the same reason)*.

Comment: ...heck, why do we even need `.index()`? These are all siblings, so you could just use the `i` from the `.each()`.

Comment: @amnotiam That's a great point, thanks – and I agree that the best thing would be testing for the root cause. However, if the element is hidden by e.g. `hide`, this is the best technique...

Comment: Ok, so I tested the speed. I wrapped each code around this statement: var start = new Date().getTime(); for (var TestPerf = 0; TestPerf < 1000; TestPerf++) { ... } alert("Milliseconds: " + (new Date().getTime() - start)); On Chrome, after doing the operation ONE THOUSAND times, and repeating the experiment 20 times for each and taking the averages: 46 milliseconds vs. 22 milliseconds. BUT, in reality, we're only doing the operation once, not 1,000 times. I prefer readability/maintability but you are right that your code is faster and I put in your code as well, but commented out.